# In Android, How can I create a simple dialog from a plain java class that extends nothing

Tags: android, dialog

I am creating my first App. The app will be a replica of the game known as tictactoe. The app is working and works perfectly in my emulator. When the user clicks on an imageview the activity calls a java class that doesn't extend anything and in that java class the code checks for a winning case and if it finds one then it returns a boolean to the Activity class which calls for the reset of all the imageviews(squares), to the original drawables and sets the winners score to display the new score. Before this reset takes place I would like to have a pop up dialog appear and say "congrats". It will have an ok button to dismiss the dialog at which point the rest of the code executes resetting the imageviews (squares) to blank ones. The point at which I want the pop up dialog to appear is between the code of my plain java class. This java class does not extend activity or context or anything. If I instantiate a "dialog" such that Dialog d = new Dialog(); of any type of dialog whether it be an alertDialog or any other, the constructor expects a context as a parameter. However since the java class does not extend anything I cannot pass the class itself as one. How else can I instantiate an instance of dialog? The java class constructor and methods are accessed from MainActivity.java but the java class itself, once again, does not extend Activity or anything else. I have found solutions for showing a dialog upon clicking a button which is in an activity but here I want the dialog to be instantiated at a certain point of code of another class after the button is clicked. Hope i didn't repeat myself too much...
My Code in the Oncreate() of the Activity class is:

```
ivtm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
            gameOver=s.play("tm", iv, tvR, tvB, currentPlayer);
            if(gameOver) {
                resetSquares();
                gameOver = false;
                s.resetGame();
            }//end if
        }
});
```

you can see the method .play returns a boolean which satisfies the following if statement.
In the java class the method play() is as follows:

```
public boolean play(String sq, ImageView ivIn, TextView Rtv, TextView Btv, ImageView currentView) {
    cv = currentView;
    setPoint(sq,ivIn);
    if(gameOver) {
        ///////////////////////////////////win message
        changePlayer(cv);
        if(player.equals("red")) {
            redScore += 1;
            updateScore(redScore,Rtv);
        } else {
            blueScore += 1;
            updateScore(blueScore,Btv);
        }//end if else
        resetGame();
        gameOver = false;
        win = true;
    }//end if gameOver
    return win;
}//end play()
```

The method setPoint sets the boolean "gameOver" to true if there is a winner. The dialog should be declared and instantiated below the comment ///////////win message

Comment: pass the Activity reference "this" into the pojo class and use it as the context to show the dialog?

Comment: Thanks mjstam that's great. I was trying to pass it through the .play() method but was actually passing the onClickListener(). Your comment suggested passing it through when I first instantiated  the constructor of the java class. Im so happy that worked.